# Onfly Translation of Header

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, translation

I use [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) to build my website with multiple language sections. I often be so concentrate on the text that I forget translate the header of files.

```
title: "This is the title"
date: 2020-03-01
shorttext: "Here come the shorttext in for the blog cards"
...
```

Now the question is, when I use grep to become the entry of title / shorttext and pipe it through translation-shell command, how can save the output of translation-shell in the double quotes of title / shorttext?

```sh
egrep 'shorttext:' $file | sed 's/shorttext: //g' | trans -brief -e bing :fr
"Ceci est un titre"
```

"Ceci est un titre" should now write to file behind shorttext. Is there a way to realize it? Thank you for help

Regards
Silvio

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep` is more or less a filter, so as soon as you use it on an input, it will generate an output which contanins less lines (in the non-trivial usecase that the pattern does not match all the lines) of the input. Whatever you pipe this output into you will not get back the lines that did not match in the `grep` command. This is to say that maybe you have to put the whole command you've written so far into a `$(…)` and use it as the replacement string of another external `sed` command.

Comment: Besides, your command seems to pipe `"Here come the shorttext in for the blog cards"` into `trans` at this for some magical reason results in `"Ceci est un titre"`, which actually the translation of `"This is the title"`, isn't it? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your command to get the translation is, you could use command substitution in another `sed` command, as in

```
sed -E 's/(^shorttext: ).*/\1"'"$(egrep 'shorttext:' $file | sed ...)"'"/' your file
```

Note that the `sed` substitution command is split into 3 strings, the first and last enlosed in single quotes, and the middle one enclosed in double quotes, so as to allow the command substitution in it, `"$(…)"`.